# Voice Recognition Python Module Stopped Working After 6 Months

Tags: python, voice-recognition, pyttsx3

I made a small voice assistant 6 months ago using the voice recognition /pyttsx3 python module and it has been working for those 6 months until as of recently it seems to have stopped working. Since when I start running the script it just doesn't seem to recognize my voice and just stays at "listening" without giving any response or error message at all.Also, I tried uninstalling/reinstalling the modules,but that didn't change anything and I have tried looking online to see if someonelse had a similar issue,but I wasn't able to find anything resembling the problem that I have.

Here is the function which I made for the voice recognition/response from my voice assistant:

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
def takeCommand(): 
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        speak("Listening...")
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-us')
        print(f"user said: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) 
        print("Say that again please")
        query = None
    return query
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,Thanks -Obunga

Comment: maybe an operating-system level issue?

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly?